# PHP: Sub class static inheritance - children share static variables?

Tags: php, inheritance, static, subclass, extend

As you can see below I have a super class (Article) and two sub classes. I want each of the sub classes to have a static array that shall hold all it's objects.

```
abstract class Article
{
    public static $articles = array(); // Variable for storing all the objects of each sub-class.

    public function add_Object_To_Array()
    {       
        array_push(self::$articles, $this);
    }
}

class Report extends Article{}
class Interview extends Article{}
```

-Making two Report objects and adding them to their array:

```
$tmp = new Report();
$tmp->add_Object_To_Array();

$tmp = new Report();
$tmp->add_Object_To_Array();
```

-Making two Interview objects and adding them to their array:

```
$tmp = new Interview();
$tmp->add_Object_To_Array();

$tmp = new Interview();
$tmp->add_Object_To_Array();

print_r(Report::$articles);
print_r(Interview::$articles);
```

-The above script spits out the two arays:

```
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; Report Object()

    [1] =&gt; Report Object()

    [2] =&gt; Interview Object()

    [3] =&gt; Interview Object()   
)
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; Report Object()

    [1] =&gt; Report Object()

    [2] =&gt; Interview Object()

    [3] =&gt; Interview Object()    
)
```

Which looks pretty similar if you ask me, but the first one should only contain Reports, and the second one only Interviews.

**1. It seems that there is only one array, why is it only one array?** 
**2. I have a static container of objects in the same class, is this bad coding? (Any suggestions?)**

I'm pretty new to php, but have a background from java.

Comment: `abstract class Article` is missing its closing `}`. `$this` in that context refers to `abstract class Article`. How will you push that on to the Array?

Comment: Thanks, but I thought:
`$tmp = new Report();
$tmp->add_Object_To_Array();`
referred to the the "Report object's function"? (OOP thinking). I'm aware of the fact that there can be no objects of the abstract class .

Comment: use `static::$articles` rather than `self::$articles`

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that, it didn't work..

Comment: @AlexP `static::` is required, but it's only part of the solution. You also need to define the variables separately.

Comment: Great! That solved it, thanks! Just as jcsanyi said!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Everything is going into only one array for two reasons:

1. The `$articles` property is only defined in the `Article` class.

   Static class properties do not get inherited the same way you might expect if you're used to non-static properties. While they **are** available to the child classes, they're still referencing a single variable on the parent class - resulting in the behavior you're seeing here where both child classes are sharing the same array.

   The only way to prevent this is to define a separate array in each of your child classes, like this:

   ```
   class Report extends Article {
       public static $articles = array();
   }
   class Interview extends Article {
       public static $articles = array();
   }
   ```

   This actually makes sense if you think of the static variable declarations as code that gets run when the class is defined. Creating a static variable and assigning an empty array to it happens when the `Article` class is defined. It doesn't happen again when the `Interview` and `Report` classes are defined. There's only one time that an empty array is getting assigned - there's only one shared variable.
2. You're using `self` in your `add_Object_To_Array()` method instead of `static`.

   - `self::` refers to the class it is defined in, so since your `add_Object_To_Array()` method is defined in the `Article` class, it'll refer to the `Article::$articles` array.
   - `static::` Is available starting in PHP 5.3, and refers to the class it is *called* on. This is known as [Late Static Binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), and will result in `add_Object_To_Array()` referring to either `Report::$articles` or `Interview::$articles` depending on the type of the object you're calling it on.

   This code will reference the two arrays that we declared in the first step:

   ```
   public function add_Object_To_Array() {
       array_push(static::$articles, $this);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! Great answer, both educating **and** problem-solving! :)

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd present an alternate solution that changes your design slightly, but doesn't require static definitions in each subclass. Depending on your usage, this may or may not be a better option than the first solution.

This solution uses [`get_class()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) to find the type of the object we're storing, and then stores it in the parent class - in a sub-array keyed by classname:

```
abstract class Article
{
    public static $articles = array();

    public function add_Object_To_Array()
    {
        // get the actual class of the current object
        $class = get_class($this);
        // define an empty subarray for this class if we haven't seen it before
        if (!isset(self::$articles[$class])) {
            self::$articles[$class] = array();
        }
        // add this object to the appropriate subarray
        array_push(self::$articles[$class], $this);
    }
}
class Report extends Article{}
class Interview extends Article{}
```

The above code does not use late static binding, so it'll work with any PHP version, instead of just PHP 5.3+.

When you run this version with your original example, you'll get output like this:

```
Array
(
    [Report] => Array
        (
            [0] => Report Object
                (
                )

            [1] => Report Object
                (
                )

        )

    [Interview] => Array
        (
            [0] => Interview Object
                (
                )

            [1] => Interview Object
                (
                )

        )

)
```

If you do have PHP 5.3 or later, you can extend this even more and use the [`get_called_class()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) function to define a `getInstances()` static method (in the `Article` class) that works like this:

```
public static function getInstances()
{
    $class = get_called_class();
    // return isset(self::$articles[$class]) ? self::$articles[$class] : array();
    if (isset(self::$articles[$class])) {
        return self::$articles[$class];
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Then you can call this method in your example like this:

```
print_r(Report::getInstances());
print_r(Interview::getInstances());
```

Comment: nice! I didn't quite catch your extended method, more precisely
`return isset(self::$articles[$class]) ? self::$articles[$class] : array();`, I'm not very familiar with this type of if-statement. Does it return an empty array if the statement is `false`?

Comment: @MathiasCiarlo I'm using the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) there. I've rewritten it to a clearer but essentially equivalent version.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for an alternative solution, apart the above good ones.
You can use PHP's late static binding (`static::`), but you also need to define the variables separately in each subclass (this will make them independent).

You can use this:

```
abstract class Article
{
    public static $articles = array();

    public function add_Object_To_Array()
    {
        array_push(static::$articles, $this);
    }
}

class Report extends Article
{
    public static $articles = array();
}

class Interview extends Article
{
    public static $articles = array();
}
```

Then when calling `add_Object_To_Array()` from each subclass, it will store the articles in separate places.

See [Late Static Bindings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)